# Define a traceless part of $\rho$

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix

I saw in a paper: $|\bar{\rho}\rangle\rangle=|\rho\rangle\rangle-|\hat{I}\rangle\rangle / 2^{n / 2}$ for the $4^n$-dimensional vector representing the traceless part of $\rho$. https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.15648v1

For example, $n=1$,
$
|\rho\rangle\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d
\end{pmatrix}, 
$
$a+d=1$.
\begin{equation}
|\hat{I}\rangle\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
|\bar{\rho}\rangle\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
a - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
b \\
c \\
d - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
$tr(\bar{\rho})=a+d-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\ne0$.

Here, why not $|\bar{\rho}\rangle\rangle=|\rho\rangle\rangle-|\hat{I}\rangle\rangle / 2^{n}$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is easy to solve if the asker is more careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not been careful enough with the factors of $2^{n/2}$. There are two of them: one in making $\hat I$ instead of $I$ and **another** when subtracting $|\hat I\rangle\rangle$. In other words, your $|\bar\rho\rangle\rangle$ is incorrect and the terms really are $a-\frac12$ etc. as you expect.

Comment: I see, there are two factors $2^{n/2}$, omg, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is right, be careful! $n=1$,
$
|\rho\rangle\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d
\end{pmatrix}, 
$
$a+d=1$.
\begin{equation}
|\hat{I}\rangle\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
|\bar{\rho}\rangle\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
a - \frac{1}{2} \\
b \\
c \\
d - \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
$tr(\bar{\rho})=a+d-1=0$.